# VBA to delete rows from a worksheet based on 2 conditions on another worksheet

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, vba

I have searched the web and tried all possible solutions, but in vain.

There are auditors looking at specific customers in specific areas.

I have three worksheets with data on it: Summary sheet, Raw Data sheet and an Area Listing sheet. The data gets transferred from the data sheet to the summary sheet, but contains areas that do not belong to the specific auditor. The area listings have an indicator Yes/No that must be used to clear the summary sheet of unwanted areas.

I therefore need to delete the unwanted areas from the Summary sheet by first matching the area names on both sheets and then delete those that are marked with a "No" on the area listing sheet.

The core coding I have tried:

```
If ActiveCell.Formula = "=VLookup(B2,Areas!C2:D,1,False)"=True _
    And Sheets("Areas").Range("D2").Value = "No" Then     
    Sheets("Summary").EntireRow.Delete
```

Where B2 is the column in Summary containing the Areas and C2 is the corresponding column in Areas with D2 the column in Areas listing the selections of Yes / No.

How do I then write the code to delete the Rows in Summary where the areas are matching in the Summary and the Areas sheet and the indicator in the Areas sheet is "No"?

I have also tried:

```
For I = LastRowCheck To 1 Step -1
     If Sheets("Summary").Range("B" & LastRowCheck).Value = _
        Sheets("Areas").Range("C" & sdRow).Value _
        And Sheets("Areas").Range("D" & NoRow).Value = "No" Then
     If DelRange is Nothing Then
       Set DelRange = Sheets("Summary").Rows(i)
  End If
  If not DelRange Is Nothing Then DelRange.EntireRow.Delete
  End If  
  Next i
```

Can somebody please tell me where I am missing the boat?

Comment: in the core code i noticed it should be: `Sheets("Summary").ACTIVECELL.entireRow.delete` the activeCell part was missing, this would cause a problem. if that still doesnt work, I did post my answer

Comment: @user1759942: I have tried both codes without success. On Code A it queries the line: if not deleted then ActiveCell.offset(1,0).offset (do not accept the second Offset) and in Code B the line set rng = Range("A1", Cells(lastrow, lastcolumn)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me, that the areas sheet is going to have.. lets say 50 different areas, and the summary sheet is going to have however many rows, each with an area from the area sheet. so multiple rows would have the same area. so, you want to loop through all the rows on the summary sheet, find the corresponding area from the area sheet, and see if that area has a "no" value in column D.

given the above understanding, the following 2 options should both work:

A)

- loop through all rows on areas sheet and load all area names with D
  column value of "No" into an array.
- loop through all rows on summary sheet
- use inner loop to check and see if current row in    summary sheet is
  found in array of "bad areas"
- delete entire row

B)

- use a loop to find all rows in the area sheet with a D column value of "No" and load the names from each of these areas into an array.
- use said array as the criteria for a data filter, filtering the area name column in the summary sheet
- delete all visible rows (ones with areas found on areas sheet with D column value of "No"

A Code:

```
Dim strArray() as variant
ReDim strArray(1 to 1)
dim deleted as boolean 'keeps track of whether row was delete or not

Sheets("Area Sheet").Activate
Range ("A1").Activate  'where assuming column a has area name
for i = 1 to lastrow
    if ActiveCell.offset(0, 3).formulaR1C1 = "No" then 'column D, I have had bad experience with .value so i always use formulaR1C1
          strArray(i) = ActiveCell.formulaR1C1
    end if
    ActiveCell.offset(1,0).activate
next

Sheets("Summary Sheet").activate
Range("A1") ' again, assuing a has area name
for i = 1 to endrow
    delete = false 'reset delete before inner loop
    for j = 1 to ubound(strArray)
         if ActiveCell.formulaR1C1 = strArray(i) then
              ActiveCell.entireRow.delete xlShiftUp
              deleted = true   
              exit for   'exits inner loop
         else
              deleted = false
         end if
    next
    if  not deleted then ActiveCell.offset(1,0).offset ' move down to next row if curent row was not deleted
next
```

B Code:

```
'use same as A code to get all areas with D Column "No" into array
Dim rng as Range

Range("A1").activate ' after activating summary sheet, again, assuming a has area name
ActiveCell.entireColumn.select
selection.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=strArray, Operator:=xlFilterValues ' this will filter so only rows with area and column D of "No" will be visible.
set rng = Range("A1", Cells(lastrow, lastcolumn)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) ' this will get all visible cells (ones that are visible with current filter condition)
rng.entirerow.delete xlshiftup 'will delete all rows in rng
```

depending on the amount of data, A) with `application.Screenupdating =false` may be faster than filter (use doesnt see whats happening behind the scenes.) do make sure to do `Application.screenupdating = true` again after to turn that back on.

code may need tweaking for spelling mistakes etc.. but basis should be there
I did not set endrow ever as everyone has their own way of getting the last row.

HTH
good luck!

Comment: I have tried both codes without success. On Code A it queries the line: if not deleted then ActiveCell.offset(1,0).offset (do not accept the second Offset) and in Code B the line set rng = Range("A1", Cells(lastrow, lastcolumn)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).

Comment: I did say there would need to be some changes for spelling mistakes etc... clearly you have no VBA experience because `ActiveCell.offset(1,0).offset` should obviously be `.activate` at the end instead of a second `.offset`. also I noticed now that I dim'd the `deleted` variable up top in A but I used `delete` later, that will need to be changed. also in A, after the line: `strArray(i) = ActiveCell.formulaR1C1` add: `ReDim strArray(1 to ubound(strArray) + 1)` within that same if statement

Comment: I have changed everything as suggested and tried other settings as well, without success. This one is winning me. The "Area" sheet contains the "No" and the Area name while the "Summary" sheet only contains the Area name corresponding to the name on the "Area" sheet. The "Summary" Area must equal the "Area" Area and the "Area" "No" must also be true to delete the entire row from "Summary". Not one of the above codes achieve that. Where do we go wrong then? I agree, I am having a trail and error process here, but nothing is really working out for me. Thank you for the inputs and the help.